# How do i fix CS0136?

Tags: c#, api, roblox

Ok I have been trying this for 4 hours.

What I'm trying to do is to get every username in this list (could be any list matching the userid ):

Example that I want to see in the console:

```
Username: sk2lly
```

and every other user on the friend list of the userid

But I keep getting this error

> CS0136: A local or parameter named 'temp' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("UserId: ");
string UserId = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();

WebClient client = new WebClient();
string useridtextbox1 = client.DownloadString("https://api.roblox.com/users/" + UserId + "/friends/");
dynamic fobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(useridtextbox1);

string temp = fobj["Username"].ToString();

foreach (string temp in fobj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(temp);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You have two variables named `temp`. Rename or delete one. This line appears to do nothing, it's a good one to delete and the problem goes away: `string temp = fobj["Username"].ToString();`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok but now it says "the word temp doesnt exist" and how is it gonna know im looking for username??

Comment: Try something like `foreach(dynamic user in fobj){Console.WriteLine(user.Username);} Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: @Steeeve i get "Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "Username". Int32 array index expected"

Comment: At which statement? Remove your line `string temp = fobj["Username"].ToString()`

Comment: @Steeeve I forgot to do this yeah it works thanks!!

Comment: @Steeeve Just coming back to say that it is not logging or printing the entire friendlist. One of my friend got 171 friends and i only get 30-50 friends.

Comment: @Skully that must have an other reason than the loop. Have you checked the whole string `useridtextbox1`? Just copy it in the clipboard and paste it in excel, then you'll see how many rows it contains. Maybe the response is limited to a certain number of friends. Or your console scrollback buffer doesn't fit all the lines.

Comment: Side note: you are much better off creating a proper class to deserialize into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach (var temp in fobj)
{
 Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString());
 Console.ReadLine();
}
```